# how to keep a value in associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the example of an associative array in php. I want to keep one of the two occurens of an element. The first and the second array comporte the name Z, so i want to keep one of them based on the key (name) and with a special condition for the score. The most important for me is to know how to do it. Here's an attempt i've done, but i failed.

```
foreach($tabs as $key => $tab){
        if($tab[$key]['name'] != $tab[$key+1]['name']){

      //do some code

  }
}

array(

       [0] => array(

                id => 1,
                name => Z
                score => 77
         )

       [1] => array(

                id => 2,
                name => Z
                score => 10
         )

      [2] => array(

                id => 3,
                name => A
                score => 55
         )
);
```

What i want to keep an array like this :

```
 array(

       [0] => array(

                id => 1,
                name => Z
                score => 77
         )

      [2] => array(

                id => 3,
                name => A
                score => 55
         )
);
```

Thanks

Comment: You can compare by `name` and `unset()` second element which contains this element.

Comment: What doesn't work for you? You can use `unset($tab[$key])`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php

Comment: I think he is searching by a way to found the duplicated values, according with: `The most important for me is to know how to do it.`

Comment: Hi, thank you for accepting my answer but the code was untested when I posted it and had a lot of bugs that I've fixed up. It is working as expected now and you can test it out on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for something like this:

```
<?php
$original_data = array(
    0 => array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Z',
        'score' => 77
    ),
    1 => array(
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Z',
        'score' => 10
    ),
    2 => array(
        'id' => 3,
        'name' => 'A',
        'score' => 55
    )
);

$highest = array();

$to_be_removed = array();

foreach($original_data as $key => &$tab)
{
    if(isset($highest[$tab['name']]['score']))
    {
        if($tab['score'] > $highest[$tab['name']]['score'])
        {
            $to_be_removed[$highest[$tab['name']]['index']] = '';

            $highest[$tab['name']]['score'] = $tab['score'];
            $highest[$tab['name']]['index'] = $key;
        }
        else
        {
            $to_be_removed[$key] = '';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $highest[$tab['name']]['score'] = $tab['score'];
        $highest[$tab['name']]['index'] = $key;
    }
}

if($to_be_removed)
{
    foreach($to_be_removed as $k=>&$v)
    {
        unset($original_data[$k]);
    }
}

print_r($original_data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `in_array()` to find it, but this function is not recursive, so you need to make your own function, like this:

```
function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
foreach($tabs as $key => $tab){
  if(in_array_r($tab['name'], $tabs){
      // it found in the whole array
      unset($tabs[$key]);
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
$new = [];

foreach ($tabs as $tab) {
    if (! isset($new[$tab['name']])) {
        $new[$tab['name']] = $tab;
    }
}

$new = array_values($new);
```

It's a 2-step solution, has the advantage it doesn't have to iterate the whole array for each check.

If you need to check for a condition (score value, etc.) for overwriting or not,

```
foreach ($tabs as $tab) {
    if ( (! isset($new[$tab['name']]))
         || shouldOverwrite($new[$tab['name'], $tab)
    ) {
        $new[$tab['name']] = $tab;
    }
}
```

You should define `function shouldOverwrite($old, $new)` comparing the stored with the current one in the iteration, with any comparation logic you wish to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare by `name` and `unset()` the subarray which contains this element.

```
$arr = array(
    0 => array(
        id => 1,
        name => Z,
        score => 77
    ),
    1 => array(
        id => 2,
        name => Z,
        score => 10
    ),
    2 => array(
        id => 3,
        name => A,
        score => 55
    )
);
$name = '';
foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
    if($name == $val['name']){
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }else{
        $name = $val['name'];                
    }
}
print_r($arr);
```

output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Z
            [score] => 77
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => A
            [score] => 55
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a good ol' unset:

```
foreach($tabs as $key => $tab){
        if (isset($tab[$key-1] && $tab[$key]['name'] != $tab[$key-1]['name']){    
            //do some code
        } elseif (isset($tab[$key-1])) && $tab[$key]['name'] == $tab[$key-1]['name']) { 
             unset($tab[$key-1]);
        }
  }
}
```

This will only work if the items are adjacent. If they are not adjacent you could first sort the array to make sure they are:

```
usort($tabs, function ($v1,$v2) {
   return strcmp($v1['name'], $v2['name']);
});
```